# What is this vertical antenna with radials pointing up

Tags: antenna, hf, vertical-antenna

I work next to "[Koninklijk Marine Kadettenkorps Afdeling Oostende](https://www.google.be/maps/place//@51.2376654,2.9315905,17z)" (Royal Marine Cadet Corps Ostend). They have an antenna that I've been wondering about for years now:

[image]

It is a vertical antenna, likely HF bands with four radials angled about 45 degrees from the vertical. So far, completely normal.

However, the verticals are pointing **up**.
I've never seen this kind of antenna. For I long time I thought maybe someone just made a mistake while putting it together, but I can't honestly believe no one would have fixed it over time.

I am not proficient in any NEC program to simulate it myself. What is this kind of antenna used for?

Comment: *could be* a capacity hat rather than ground radials - we cannot see what's at the antenna bottom.

Comment: I'm thinking it's the same kind of "fan-ish" multiband verts as seen in https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/18066/8016

Comment: This is very interesting! However, I don't think that *anyone* could model this antenna, because of at least 2 unknowns: **1.** what is inside the black areas in the lower (larger diameter) and **2.** upper (smaller diameter) vertical sections? One can only guess. For all we know, the black area in the upper section is a feedpoint.

Comment: Changing the angle of radials on a ground plane changes its feedpoint impedance. *Might* the elevated radials (which seem to be connected) serve to increase it? Just a thought.

Comment: @MikeWaters I agree with that this is sadly all guesswork, unless someone happens to recognize their antenna model in the photo (which might reasonably happen!); my bit of speculation: this electrically "widens" the upper half of the antenna, and assuming actual (dirt) ground is used as (zero-potential) ground plane, that would make the antenna more wideband; somewhere between a monopole and a discone.

Comment: I'll go and have a look if there is a position from which I can see the bottom of the antenna, but I don't think so.
Just realized I know someone who works at radio comms for defence, he might know either the antenna or someone with more info. I'll ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it through help from a friend.

It is a differential correction (dGPS) transmitter for Ostend on 312kHz.

A seemingly similar antenna (for same frequency band) can be found for example on the [Banten website.](https://www.banten.it/en/air-traffic/408-uhf-tbt-antenna-220-400-mhz.html), with the datasheet here: [Datasheet](https://www.banten.it/en/index.php?controller=attachment&id_attachment=66).

In case the datasheet ever gets lost (dead link), the most important things to note are:

- Frequency: 200-1800kHz
- Max power: 250W
- Capacitance: 130pF (@300kHz)
- Vertical polarisation

The radials would be to increase bandwith.

Still looking around to find more on the antenna design though...

Comment: Very good! If no one else posts a better answer soon then you should mark this as accepted. This keeps the bot from automatically pushing it to the top (because no answer is accepted).